# Drawing lost when resizing java applet window

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
/* <applet code="kp.class" width = 400 height = 400></applet> */ 
public class kp extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener
{
    Graphics g,h;
    static int x,y,a,b;
    Dimension d;
    public void init()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);   
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        a++;
        x=e.getX();
        y=e.getY();
        g=getGraphics();
                g.setColor(Color.red);
        if(a>5)
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(0,0,x,y);

    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g1)
    {
        super.paint(g1);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the code. 
When I move the mouse, a red line is drawn. Now when I resize/minimize and maximize the window, the drawing on the applet is lost.

What can I do so that the drawing does not get lost?

Comment: I wonder why people are still using applets.

Comment: 1) `@Override
    public void paint(Graphics g1)
    {
        super.paint(g1);
    }` this override is completely pointless, since the code is overriding the method to 'change' it to do ..exactly the same thing it would have done if it was ***not*** overridden, 2) `g=getGraphics();` Not the correct way to do custom graphics on a component. Components should draw whenever requested to do so by the JRE, and that is a complicated set of circumstances that includes when the window is resized. 3) When an applet is embedded in HTML, it will have a fixed size, but the paint methods might be ..

Comment: .. called when the browser window is restored, comes to front or any number of other circumstances. 4) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 5) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: 5) The correct way to go about painting in this situation is to add the lines to a list and call `repaint()`. Within the `paint(Graphics)` method, iterate the list and draw each line to the supplied `Graphics` object.

Comment: @Jay Typically because lazy or incompetent teachers are using outdated materials.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yea. The op is from India. And i think we are in same university as i have that on my course next year. :/